# Linear Algebra -- Finding The Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We are asked to find the inverse of the following matrix, provided the inverse exists:
$$
    \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & a & b+c\\
    1 & b & a+c\\
    1 & c & a+b
    \end{array}\right]
$$

I cannot seem to arrive at any definitive solution. What I do know is that we augment the matrix with the identity matrix and perform elementary row operations such as addition, subtraction and multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $a_{i3} = (a+b+c)a_{i1}-a_{i2}$.

Comment: Any more hints is appreciated

Comment: @user4640007: Columns are not linearly independent, hence $\det=0$, 
inverse does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response. An answer with more clarification for others is appreciated.